# NGINX - sites-enabled files are not active

Tags: nginx

nginx is serving an index.html file from /usr/share/nginx/html, rather than from the /usr/share/nginx/html2 which is indicated in my sites-enabled/www virutal host file. My concern is that my sites-enabled/www file is not active.

in my nginx.conf http block, I have the following:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www file, I have the following:

```
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
server_name *.my_host_name.com;
root /usr/share/nginx/html2;
index index.html index.htm
```

any ideas why nginx is still serving up an index.html file from the /usr/share/nginx/html folder rather than the /usr/share/nginx/html2 folder as indicated in the settings above?

Comment: try removing the word `default` the `listen` line in the file `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

Comment: What's in the error log?

Comment: Why "ipv6only=on" ? Will it not disable the site being viewable on ipv4?